# Cannot Resolve R after Update Android Studio to v13

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I've got problem when executing gradle after my android studio updated to version 1.3

So this is the error message

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Otniel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I don't know what was happened, but this is my approach to fix my error (which is not produce any working solution)

1. change my build tools from project structure settings :
   compile sdk version : API 22: Android 5.1 
   build tools version 22.0.1
   (sync gradle and error still the same with the above message)

Then I continue the first setting (point 1) and add this 2nd setting
2. change gradle 1.2.3 to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
(1.2.3 produce the same error as the message above)
(with 1.3.0 still produce the same error)

3. try to revert back the build tools to v 21 and android lolipop v 5
   with combination of gradle : com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0, and com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3

When I revert to 1.1.3 or 1.0.0 (for the gradle plugin) I still got the same error.

When I change the gradle to 1.1.3, the console returns a message to use the gradle plugin version that match with build tools sdk (v 24)

But every combination that I use is still return an error message (still the same, like the message above)

Also I've tried to delete impl and .idea folder, and reimport the project, still have the same error.

And my android studio cannot resolve R symbol as the effect.

So what should I do to fix this?

[EDITED]
This is my gradle code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vanwellis.vinnomobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

I got these 2 errors, after seeing it carefully :
D:\Projects\Android\MyProj\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
D:\Projects\Android\MyProj\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.

Maybe my additional information are usefull

Comment: could we see your build.grade?

Answer (score 2):

After updating Android Studio recently, I also had this problem. What worked for me was to expand res, then go through every child folder in res and expand them (you can close them right after.)

Close all classes you have open and in the system bar select **Build** > **Make Project**.

Comment: Great answer! This should be accepted. Worked for me! Silly how an update to android studio can screw with existing projects.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it's seems not working for me? May I know what your gradle configuration is? and this gradle code :
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21'
did you use v7:21 or using the new one?

and these grade code :
compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

did you changed to the new one (in my case 23.0.1)